# Using NSubstitute with a vb.net module

Tags: vb.net, nsubstitute

We have some existing static methods that are grouped in VB modules.

I want to introduce unit testing to the company, and am looking into using NUnit and NSubstitute.

I can't seem to create a Substitute for the VB module I want to test, or find any examples of how to do this. I am trying to do something like:

```
Dim Sub = Substitute.For(MyModule)()
```

but VB tells me 'MyModule is a type and cannot be used as an expression'.

If I try

```
Dim Sub = Substitute.For(Of MyModule)()
```

VB tells me 'Module 'MyModule' cannot be used as a type'.

Have I got the syntax wrong or am I trying to do something stupid?

Comment: Was already editing the post to show my attempt, Trickery

Comment: NSub works by deriving from the class or implementing the interface being substituted, and replacing the standard behaviour with substitute behaviour (Castle DynamicProxy does the hard work here). AFAICT VB modules can not be proxied like this (compiled as class w/private ctor, static/shared members) so NSub won't be able to do anything with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not appropriate to unit test Modules and Shared methods (static classes and methods in C#) with a mocking framework because:

- Modules (static classes  in C#) cannot:

  - inherit from base classes
  - implement interfaces
  - and thus, be mocked
- Shared methods (static methods in C#) in mocked instances cannot be called

So, to unit test a Module or a class with Shared methods you need to do so directly. Example: (Unit test attributes omitted...)

```
Public Class A
    Public Shared Function Go(a As Integer) As Integer
        Return a + 10
    End Function
End Class

Public Class TestClass
    Public Sub Test()
        Assert.AreEqual(A.Go(5), 15)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I feel like the .NET world could learn a lot from frameworks like RSpec

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli in the similar fashion that RSpec learned from JBehave? Everyone learns from everyone and the better ideas usually get implemented everywhere. Would you mind explaining the -1? If there's something wrong with the answer I'd either like to correct it or delete it.

Comment: It's just that it should be possible to mock whatever you want, because we aren't always starting from scratch. If you are needing to test legacy code some enterprise client came up with over a decade ago. It's not that your answer isn't correct, it's that the whole mentality of testing in c# and VB needs to change... And it is changing... slowly... But currently the newest features are only available to the rich, requiring vs ultimate. :-(

Answer (score 0):

make sure your sending in an interface and I wouldn't use a variable name as Sub as it's a reserved type.

Example 
  Dim fakeWebRequestService = Substitute.For(Of IWebRequestService)()